# Loop over groupby, plot each group with different set value for 1 column each time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, plot

I have the following dataset:

| participant | exercise | area | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | DI | AGI | 3 |
| 3 | DI | BAL | 0 |
| 3 | Lu | POW | 4 |
| 3 | Lu | END | 4 |
| 3 | Ca | STR | 3 |
| 3 | Ro | AGI | 3 |
| 7 | Be | STR | 0 |
| 7 | Be | END | 0 |
| 7 | So | AGI | 3 |
| 21 | Sq | STR | 0 |
| 21 | Jj | AGI | 3 |
| 22 | Fj | RES | 2 |
| 22 | Fj | STR | 0 |
| 22 | Cu | AGI | 0 |
| 36 | Be | END | 4 |
| 36 | Be | RES | 3 |
| 36 | Be | STR | 2 |
| 46 | Mc | STR | 0 |
| 46 | Bo | AGI | 0 |

I want to create 2 graphs for every different value in the column 'exercise'.

This is just a sample. in reality we have 300 participants, 50 exercises, 6 areas, and level ranges from -4 to 4.

The graphs should be:

- Bar plot of average level per area of each specific exercise

  ```
                sns.barplot(ax=ax1,
                            x="impact level",
                            y="area",
                            data = mean_il_EI,
                            ci = 'sd')
                plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
                plt.title( name + ":" + "Distribution of opinions per area")
                plt.ylabel('Area')
                plt.xlabel("Average Impact")
  ```
- Count plot of number of levels recorded per area of each specific exercise

  ```
                sns.countplot(x="level",
                            hue="area",
                            data = data)
                plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
                plt.title(str(exercise) + 'Number of evaluations per area')
                plt.ylabel('Number of evaluations')
                plt.xlabel("Level")
  ```

I need a way to create a loop in which each value of the column 'exercise' is evaluated separately.

Each graph must represent only the data related to that particular value of 'exercise'

As you can see, I already have the code for the specific graphs. I only need:

- Loop set-up
- Dataset manipulation

Comment: Can you provide your data with little more examples in text format ? it would be easy for us to provide you solutions based on that.

Comment: here is a larger sample of my data!

Comment: You can loop through groups with `for group in df.groupby("exercise"):`

Comment: Thanks! However, the plots are still not printing. What data should I use in my countplots? What would I set x, y, hue to if originally I had wanted x="level", hue="area", data = data?